# Yum crashed with Keyboard Interrupt error

Tags: python-3.x, redhat, yum, fedora16

I installed the newer version of python (3.2.3) than the one available in Fedora16 (python2.7)

And now `yum` stops working. It shows the following error.

```
[root@localhost yum-3.4.3]# yum
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 30
   except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please advice as how to resolve the error. It would be helpful as I am not able to update or install any package.

Comment: Don't replace the system python on a Fedora machine. You should have installed python3 as something like /usr/local/bin/python3.

Comment: In 2019, with python2 all but deprecated, one should not have to worry about linking a python3 executable to /usr/bin/python. It is incredibly lazy for a package to have this issue when the fix is literally to add a single character to your python2 files (ie `#!/usr/bin/python2` vs `#!/usr/bin/python`)

Answer (score 146):

Because `yum` does not support `Python3`.
You can run command `vi /usr/bin/yum`, change `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2` in first line.
Thus you can run the command `yum` by `Python2` instead of `Python3`.

Note however that **this will make your setup unsupported and thus unmaintainable (as does what you did). You will likely have other similar problems in the future with other system packages.**
If you want to use an alternative Python installation, consider installing it into `/usr/local`, `/opt` or using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

Comment: For AWS Linux 2 AMI users: if you also get a OSError even updating /usr/bin/yum  make sure start of file : 
 /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down is also edited to python2

Answer (score 64):

This issue happens when user upgrades to python3, Just simply edit the file --> /usr/bin/yum  and change to first line to -->  "#!/usr/bin/python2"

The above solution wouldn't solve the all yum dependency problems, its better to run the below commands.

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3  (Mark latest python as python3)

sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python (nake 2.7 as default python)

THanks,
Daman

Comment: I tried all solutions, yours was the one to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are the one who solved the problem. Good finding. Thanks

Comment: Yes I confirm Thanks.

Comment: yes, changing the `#!/usr/bin/python` just lead to more downstream issues in yum commands. This is much more livable.

Answer (score 25):

I'm guessing you installed Python 3.2.3 from source and used "make install" as the last command. That command has the unfortunate side-effect of replacing the system installed version command "python" with the new version. Using "make altinstall" doesn't replace "python".

The command "python" is just a symbolic link to "python2", which in turn is a symbolic link to "python2.7". You should be able to restore "python" by executing the following command:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s python2 python
```

Comment: I managed to do a little bit different : sudo ln -s python2.6 python

Comment: in 2019, with python2 all but deprecated, one should not have to worry about linking a python3 executable to `/usr/bin/python`. It is incredibly lazy for a package to have this issue when the fix is literally to add a single character to your python2 files (ie `#!/usr/bin/python2` vs `#!/usr/bin/python`)

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven the OP mentioned that this is in Fedora 16 [which is EOL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle#Maintenance_Schedule) since [02.2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_version_history#Fedora_18).

Comment: Got an error: `ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘python’: File exists`. I have to use `sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python` to make it work.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks Damanvir!  Changing the line in /usr/bin/yum worked!

This is a little off topic and might be removed but it might help someone.

These are the steps I used to install Python 3.7 on Centos and fix the yum error.

Download from https://www.python.org/

```
tar -xvf
./configure --enable-optimizations

make
make install
```

OR

```
make altinstall
```

*make altinstall is used to prevent replacing the default python binary file /usr/bin/python.*

```
cd /usr/bin
```

## Remove the current symbolic link to the previous version

```
rm python
```

OUTPUT:   rm: remove symbolic link ‘python’? y

## Find the location of the new version

```
whereis python3.7
 OUTPUT: python3: /usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

## Verify this is correct

```
  /usr/local/bin/python3.7 --version
  OUTPUT: Python 3.7.0
```

## Create a symbolic link to the location of the new version

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 python

python --version
```

OUTPUT:  Python 3.7.0

## Yum commands will show the following error:

```
  File "/bin/yum", line 30
      except KeyboardInterrupt, e:

  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

## Change the top line of this file from using python to python2

```
  vi /usr/bin/yum 
    #!/usr/bin/python2
```

Reference: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/

Answer (score 5):

The real answer - to ensure that you are back on a supportable version of python (in the event you are looking at this for an issue with RHEL 7).

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo unlink python
sudo ln -s python2 python
```

Answer (score 3):

Your yum looks for python2.  Let's use 'alternatives' to **switch between** *pythons2* and *python3*.

- run --> sudo alternatives --config python
- Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number:

If you don't configure it. How to do that?

- sudo alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python
  /usr/local/bin/python3.8 60
- sudo alternatives --install
  /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50

Answer (score 0):

It's only a binary link issue. You can copy the working `/usr/bin/python2` from any system and copy to current system location `/usr/bin/python2`

```
#cd /usr/bin

#ln -s python2 python
```