# How to set Python3.5.2 as default Python version on CentOS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, centos, python-3.5

Is there a way to set the Python 3.5.2 as the default Python version on CentOS 7? currently, I have Python 2.7 installed as default and Python 3.5.2 installed separately.

I used the following commands

```
mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python-old
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

but after that `yum` gives the error.

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

is there something I'm missing here?

NOTE: its the similar but opposite question of [Linux CentOS 7, how to set Python2.7 as default Python version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44730002/linux-centos-7-how-to-set-python2-7-as-default-python-version)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

If this

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/python
```

doesn't work (it should)

you could just add an alias into your `/home/.bashrc`with this command:

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python3.5"
```

and if this does not work either you should just use virtual env. Read this [page](https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to get started.

Comment: you are right, I tried aliasing, but the module `libtorrent` I'm installing still consider Python 2.7. because python 2.7 path is still same

Comment: anyway. using `sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` command, I'm able to use the Python 3.5.2 as default but I think `Yum` is somehow dependent upon 2.7 so, I can't use yum command with Python 3

Comment: Thank you @Veltro I'm stuck with this problem for the last 5 hours.

Comment: I tried uninstalling python and got this error `Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
`

Comment: someone says "Yum itself is implemented in Python I believe... So removing Python shoots your own foot pretty well!" here in comment https://serverfault.com/questions/844677/server-wiped-after-yum-remove-python

Comment: i suggest the alternatives method

Comment: Incomplete answer, how about pip and everything else needed?

Comment: I understand, it would have been nice to change the default environment rather than just the python binary. Thx!

Comment: In this command "sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python" should be modified according to the python version you have

Comment: @Liam when you said `alias python="/usr/bin/python3.5"` do you mean `python3.5` is a directory/folder?

Comment: This solution is creating another problem. Yum is working on python 2 only, changing default python to 3 will crash yum. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213520/yum-crashed-with-keyboard-interrupt-error

Answer (score 81):

I would suggest using ***alternatives*** instead.

As super-user (*root*) run the following:

```
# Start by registering python2 as an alternative
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50

# Register python3.5 as an alternative
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 60

# Select which Python version to use
alternatives --config python
```

The last command will ask you to choose between registered/installed ***alternatives***.

As always, well most of the time anyways, you can check out the manual ([*linux man pages*](https://web.archive.org/web/20200523111449/https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/alternatives-command)) using this simple command

```
man alternatives
```

Note:

Altho this answer refers to/make use of specific *Python* versions, the *alternatives* command, it's concepts and uses remain the same regardless of version numbers. It is strongly suggested that you read/learn more about the ***alternatives*** command in order to understand how it can help you better manage and use your system. Also, there is a good chance that some will correct bad/unusual practices currently in use on their machines. I see it with a great majority of people which i introduce to the concept. Here is a [link to a very good and simple explanation of the ***alternatives*** command](https://web.archive.org/web/20200523111449/https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/alternatives-command).

Comment: What does the 50 and 60 do for alternatives?

Comment: It has to do with the "weight" of the option or the priority as the manpages says. Higher priorities take precendence if no alternative is manually selected.

Comment: Remember that this will not do you any good if python version is hardcoded in the files (check the shebang on top...)

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Although symlinks "work", they bypass the alternatives layers which offer important improvements for things like Java, Python, etc with multiple active versions available.

Comment: Is there a "complete" solution that will also make the headers from python3-devel package the default?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the comment. I get what dev headers are but i don't understand what is the idea behind having any 'default' since there is most likely nothing to be executed from the installation rpm. I could be wrong. I'm assuming that if you set the alternatives to any other python than default and build something using said python, it would use the appropriate header from it's current running version. Can you elaborate? Or better yet, ask a question with a reference to this one with more details. Maybe check PYTHONPATH, PYTHONHOME environment variables.

Comment: As this is done, `yum` will complain like this

File "/usr/bin/yum", line 30
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So you need to choose python2 as default. CentOS 7 is in the case.

Comment: I've used simply `alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3` and it works fine.

Comment: For this simple form to work, there must already be a set alternatives for name 'python' otherwise, nothing happens, just fails silently

Answer (score 10):

Option 1) Creating a soft link actually has a drawback. "yum" does not support Python3. so, if you still decide to go with symlink creation then you also need to update the /usr/bin/yum

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

And update the shebang line with #!/usr/bin/python2 in /usr/bin/yum file

Option 2) use alternatives

```
alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.x 60
alternatives --config python
```

Option 3) create an alias in bash_profile

```
alias python="/usr/bin/python3"
```

Answer (score 5):

As the question goes, Linux CentOS 7, how to set Python3.5.2 as default Python version?

Will like to complement @OldFart's answer( Unforunately, can't comment else I would have).

[when using the install param with update-alternatives, you can set the priority in auto mode. Implicitly saying that the alternative with the highest priority will be the default alternative should no alternative have been set manually. using the above answer as an](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux) example,

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50
```

will set the python2 alternative with a priority of 50, and

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.5 60
```

will set the python3.5 alternative with a priority of 60.
and by default, the python 3.5 becomes the default python executable for the python command.

should you want to change your default python alternative,

```
update-alternatives --config python
```

Find this a better approach as i don't have to modify my path files.

Comment: as a side note, 'update-alternatives' is what you would use on debian-based distributions. redhat and related 'alternatives' is inspired from the former but are not the same. 'update-alternatives' is a symlink to 'alternatives' on redhat distributions that i believe can help smoothing out transitions from debian to redhat for server admin or the likes. I figured it would be good to include this as the OP clearly states he rides a centos release.

Comment: yes, you're correct. Had to search it out. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

Using `alternatives` to set default to python3.6 still breaks yum. To fix change the python interpreter to `/usr/bin/python2.7` in two files.

```
[root@centos7 ~]# cat /usr/bin/yum
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
[root@centos7 ~]# cat /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
```

I found the following article to be useful:
https://rakeshjain-devops.medium.com/how-to-install-python-3-on-centos-7-7-using-yum-and-source-and-set-as-default-1dee13396f7

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide some additional context around why yum was broken in the OP, and why I think the `alternatives` method is the best approach. Perhaps there are other best practices, but I've made some discoveries and would like to share my findings.

Assuming 3.5.2 was:

1. installed separately (as suggested by OP) similar to the steps: [Python Installation Procedure From Source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-python-2-7-6-and-3-3-3-on-centos-6-4#python-installation-procedure-from-source)
2. the --prefix option for ./configure was updated from the default --prefix = /usr/local/bin to --prefix = /usr/bin/python3

The command to link 'separately installed 3.5.2' at the location /usr/bin/python3 to system python at /usr/bin/python overwrote or otherwise modified system python, breaking yum.

This approach complements @OldFart 's answer and hopefully provides some additional perspective around root cause of why a separately installed python can cause issues.

`update-alternatives` was a breath of fresh air for a similar problem I ran into

Comment: Don't forget that, and again, 'update-alternatives' is a Debian-based command and is usually not present on Redhat and related distributions. I feel it needed to be clarified since the original question clearly states the OP runs a CentOS distibution.