# Why i got syntax error python - pip on Centos

Tags: python, openssl, pip, centos, pyopenssl

i upgrade pip. But after the upgrade have some syntax error.

i try install python 3.x but not fixed.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 92
    _blocking_errnos = {errno.EAGAIN, errno.EWOULDBLOCK}
```

I try to install pyopenssl

----------UPDATE----------------

i try to install python36u i got some errors

```
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libgdbm_compat.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libgdbm.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libffi.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1):

python2.6 is not supported anymore, try to change you SYS PATH to point for new python and pip

check this : [Python ENV](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_environment.htm)

alternatively you can use the following:

```
/path/to/pip3 install ....
/path/to/python3 <NAME_OF_THE_SCRIPT>
```

Comment: i install python 3.x but default python version still 2.6. How can i change? Just i try to  run https://github.com/narbehaj/ssl-checker

Comment: you need to set your PATH something like `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"` that is depend where your python3 is installed you may found it out using `which python3`

Comment: I update my answer for a workaround if you want to keep python2.6 the default for your system

Comment: i won't keep python2.6 but now i got some errors try to python3.  updated first question

Answer (score 1):

Change your Default python version using this link [Change default python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542690/linux-centos-7-how-to-set-python3-5-2-as-default-python-version)

you have installed pyopenssl for python2 environment. so first uninstall it.

check version: python3.6 -V, pip3 -V etc 
While installing pyopenssl or any software use pip3.

use **sudo pip3 install pyopenssl** or **pip3 install pyopenssl**,
It will work.

Comment: i try install python 3 again but i got some errors.
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libgdbm_compat.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libgdbm.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)

Comment: This is because of some dependency problem. don't uninstall python2 otherwise you need to reinstall the centOS again. if you did then the dependancy problem will not go anyway.   https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 0):

----------UPDATE----------------

i try to install python36u i got some errors

```
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5(XZ_5.0)(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libgdbm_compat.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libgdbm.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: liblzma.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libffi.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: python36u-libs-3.6.8-1.el7.ius.x86_64 (ius)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```