# How to change default python version when no super-user rights are provided

Tags: python, linux, centos

I'm accessing an external computer with a CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 os where I don't have any super-user rights. Because of this, changing the current python version from 2.7.5 to version 3.6.8 doesn't work using the [sudo or alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542690/how-to-set-python3-5-2-as-default-python-version-on-centos/48757130#48757130) approaches as suggested in most posts concerning this problem. Also, adding a line to the `.bashrc` file didn't fix this.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: can you use a virtual environment?

Comment: You should not be changing the default Python version of your OS anyway, whether or not you have superuser rights. All sorts of things will likely break if you do.

Comment: I don't know, how can I check this? I'm not very familiar with virtual environments.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Hm but there's some code that I need to run on that computer and initially, this problem arose from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56364247/typeerror-object-arrays-are-not-currently-supported-in-scipy-sparse-matrix-mult). That's why I want to update the python version. However, I might be mistaken and the problem's root actually lies somewhere else.

Comment: If there's code you need to run under a certain Python version, then run it under that Python version. No need to change the default version of your entire OS.

Comment: I see, I should look elsewhere to solve my initial problem. Thanks anyway!