# Set python 3 as default python version in CentOS

Tags: python, centos, yum

I have installed python 3.6 on my CentOS machine by following the guide at https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-on-centos-7/, which installs python 3 with the following:

```
sudo yum install rh-python36
```

The default python version, however, is still python 2. The guide mentions I can run python 3 by first running `scl enable rh-python36 bash`, and then python 3 will be used. However, this only works for that session - logging out and back in will revert back to python 2. According to [How to set Python3.5.2 as default Python version on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542690/how-to-set-python3-5-2-as-default-python-version-on-centos), python 3 can be set as the default with the following:

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

However, this doesn't work for me as for some reason I don't have any python3 file in `/usr/bin/` - I only have `python`, `python2`, `python2.7`, `python2.7-config`, `python2-config` and `python-config` (despite installing python 3 with yum as above).

Comment: you can find full path to python3 using `which python3` and then you can use this path with `ln -fs`. But Linux use Python for many elements in system and puting `python3` in place of `python` can makes problem - system may crash because some functions in `python3` works different then in `python2`.

Comment: you can put `scl enable rh-python36 bash` in file `~/.bashrc` and it will run it everytime when you login.

Comment: @furas I need to use python 3 for cron jobs run automatically by the server, would putting ``scl enable rh-python36 bash`` in ``~/.bashrc`` work in that case?

Comment: can't use use `python3 script.py` in cron ?

Comment: BTW: Linux uses "shebang" (`#!`) in first line of script to inform system what program uses to run script. If you use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in script (and set it executeble `chmod +x script.py`) then it should always use `python3` to run this script.

Comment: Unfortunately on my server ``python3`` loads a different version of python (3.6.3) which has some issues on my server as opposed to the python loaded by ``scl enable rh-python36 bash`` which is 3.6.9

Comment: then use full path to you python - `/full/path/to/your/python script.py` or in shebang `#!/full/path/to/your/python`

Comment: @furas Thanks, I can run ``/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python script.py`` (``/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/python`` being the location of the python that ``scl enable rh-python36 bash`` loads)

Answer (score 2):

First, run

```
$ scl enable rh-python36 bash
```

to switch python version.

Second, run

```
$ which python
```

to find out the exact path of python3.6 binary.

Third, edit ~/.bashrc.

```
$ vim ~/.bashrc
```

and add below line.

```
alias python='/opt....(the path you found by "which python")'
```

and save the file.