# How to fix -- bash: /usr/bin/python: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: python, python-3.6, rhel, rhel7

I wanted to make python3 my default on rhel so I followed the following at [How to set Python3.5.2 as default Python version on CentOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542690/how-to-set-python3-5-2-as-default-python-version-on-centos)

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

It changed the default to `3.6.8`

```
root@rhel:~# python -V
Python 3.6.8
```

Then I tried yum install python-pip:

```
root@rhel:~# yum install python-pip
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 30
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This happened when I tried a few other commands.  I tried reverting the changes by

```
root@rhel:~# sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python
```

But am running into

```
root@rhel:~# python -V
bash: /usr/bin/python: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I guess from what Im reading in places I need to break the sym links. The following is whats in my /usr/bin/

[image]

ls -l /usr/bin | grep python

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          15 Oct 21 14:12 python -> /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          14 Aug  8 05:53 python-config -> python2-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root           9 Aug  8 05:51 python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          16 Aug  8 05:53 python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root        7144 Jun 11 10:34 python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root        1835 Jun 11 10:34 python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root           9 Aug  8 05:51 python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          16 Aug  8 05:53 python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          20 Aug  8 05:53 python3-debug -> /usr/bin/python3.6dm
-rwxr-xr-x    2 root root       11336 Jun 11 15:17 python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          17 Aug  8 05:53 python3.6-config -> python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root       11336 Jun 11 15:17 python3.6dm
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root         175 Jun 11 15:16 python3.6dm-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root        3396 Jun 11 14:54 python3.6dm-x86_64-config
-rwxr-xr-x    2 root root       11336 Jun 11 15:17 python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root         173 Jun 11 15:16 python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root root        3403 Jun 11 14:54 python3.6m-x86_64-config
```

Comment: What does ```ls -l /usr/bin | grep python``` show?

Comment: A bunch!  I put the results at the bottom of my question @LampToast

Comment: `ln -fs /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python` made `/usr/bin/python` a symlink to itself, creating an infinite loop of symlinks.  You instead should make `/usr/bin/python` a symlink to one of the other ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this line of the result

```sh
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root root          15 Oct 21 14:12 python -> /usr/bin/python
```

tells us that the symbolic link `python` points to itself which is giving you the "Too many levels" error.

you can remove the link via

```sh
rm python
```

or reset the link to python3 using

```
ln -fs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

(probably need sudo for both of these)

The `yum` install error is a separate issue, though

Comment: Thank you for taking time to explain this.   Back to python3 python -V
Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 2):

`ln -fs /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python` creates a recursive symlink - i.e. it points to itself.

`yum` seems to be written with Python 2 syntax, so revert that symlink back:

```
sudo ln -fs python2 /usr/bin/python
```

Then find a way to make Python 3 the default which doesn't break your package manager. E.g. [an alias](https://askubuntu.com/a/321000/301745)

See [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) for the rationale of keeping Python 2 as default.

P.s. I'm not familiar with RHEL but all this matches with my experience with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I exit root account (crtl+D) and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with output when running *yum* following resolution of symlink for **/usr/bin/python**. (following error received):

```
File "/usr/bin/yum", line 30
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The solution **LampToast** and **wjandrea** provided assisted in resolving my symlink issue.  Although I noticed I had to link python2 vs python3.x - once I did this *yum* began working without errors.  Also, if you happen to make use of package alternatives symlink to their location may need to be altered.  I simply removed mine all together as I did not need them within my environment.

Steps in order as follows:

1. return *python* packages within **/usr/bin** - to include symlink(s)

```
root@rhel:~# sudo ls -l /usr/bin | grep python
```

2. remove *python* from **/usr/bin**

```
root@rhel:~# sudo rm python
```

3. apply symlink specific to *python2* to **/usr/bin/python**

```
root@rhel:~# sudo ln -fs /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```

4. verify python version - verifies issue resolution of package not being recognized

```
root@rhel:~# sudo python -V
```

5. install *yum-utils* to verify additional missing packages

```
root@rhel:~# sudo yum -y install yum-utils.noarch yum-verify
```

6. identify missing binaries - **performed this check to verify no-known-issues were present**.  (*Usually the case with the issues you are receiving*)

```
root@rhel:~# sudo yum verify --verify-filenames='*bin/*'
```

7. the output from previous command will display the missing binaries, simply reinstall using following command

```
root@rhel:~# sudo yum -y reinstall package_name
```

Note: You are able to perform step #6 over again to ensure no-known-issues are present.

I was going to recommend starting a new thread in case someone required assistance with further troubleshooting.  However, I decided to modify my answer and share the knowledge I just gained through experiencing this issue myself.