# How do I initialize / switch to python3 from python2 in terminal?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just created my first AWS EC2 instance. I used `sudo yum install python3 -y` to install Python3 but when I check the version via `python --version` it says Python 2.7.16. How do I switch versions?

Comment: Use the `python3` command

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. Afterwards, I checked the version again and it said 2.7.

Comment: As in, use `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: How do I remove Python2? sudo yum uninstall python didn't work.

Comment: `$ alias python=python37`

Answer (score 3):

You can either invoke python 3 with `python3` directly from the terminal, or create an alias by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` file:

`alias python=python3`

More details and troubleshooting tips available in this [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3).

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. You could explicitly request `python3`, invoking it as-is, instead of just `python`, i.e.:

   ```
   $ python3
   Python 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15)
   [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>>
   ```
2. As per [`@Nick Walsh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61165250/6506157)'s answer, you can create a shell [`alias(1)`](https://manpage.me/?alias) that just expands `python` to `python3` by putting the following either into `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or even `.bash_aliases`:

   ```
   alias python=python3
   ```

   Granted `python3` is in your `PATH`, this will work without a hitch, with the added benefit that this is a *per user* setting, meaning you won't be changing the system-wide `python` interpreter (since `python` remains pointing to `/usr/bin/python2`). If you'd like, you can opt for a system-wide alias as well by modifying `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bashrc`, adding the `alias` there.
3. You could replace the `python` symlink, linking it to `python3` instead.

   You can achieve this using [`ln(1)`](https://manpage.me/?ln) (pay close attention to the `#` vs. `$` prompt, meaning you require root privileges to issue this command. Using `sudo` will suffice):

   ```
   # ln -sf /usr/bin/python{3,}
   ```

   I'm leveraging bash's string expansion features to avoid repetition. The command effectively expands to:

   ```
   # ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
   ```

   This is probably recommended for the sake of portability (when it comes to scripting).
4. The latter alternative might work up until python gets updated, replacing the default `python` interpreter again with `python2`. [@kichik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61165139/how-do-i-initialize-switch-to-python3-from-python2-in-terminal#comment108207733_61165254) pointed out the use of [`alternatives(8)`](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=alternatives&manpath=CentOS+7.1) to adequately (and truly persistently) configure your `python` interpreter.

   As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757130/6506157), you can issue the following commands to *install* and configure your default `python` interpreter:

   ```
   # alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 50
   # alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 60
   # alternatives --config python

   There are 2 programs which provide 'python'.

     Selection    Command
   -----------------------------------------------
      1           /usr/bin/python2
   *+ 2           /usr/bin/python3

   Enter to keep the current selection[+], or type selection number: 2
   $ alternatives --display python
   python - status is manual.
    link currently points to /usr/bin/python3
   /usr/bin/python2 - priority 50
   /usr/bin/python3 - priority 60
   Current `best' version is /usr/bin/python3.
   $ python
   Python 3.7.6 (default, Feb 26 2020, 20:54:15)
   [GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)] on linux
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   >>>
   ```

Comment: [Nick Walsh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61165250/6506157) proposes another nifty and potentially easier alternative that comes in the form of a shell alias, masking `python3` behind the `python` alias. This differs from the symbolic link approach which destructively replaces the default python interpreter system-wide. This approach is user-specific. I'm guessing that, in this case, it isn't very important.

His answer also includes a terribly helpful question! Be sure to check that out.

Comment: [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48757130/492773) is the more official way of doing this. Otherwise your symlinks may be overwritten by upgrades.

Comment: Ahh, I was unaware of this! That's probably the best option to configure it system-wide then. I'll work on adding that to my answer, thank you!